# VB.NET fill combobox from access from only one field

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, combobox, recordset

I am still learning vb.net and I am messing with accessing a database. I have a combobox that I want to be populated by a only one field from access, because I do not want to create many columns, the field is like this "Very good; Good; Normal; Bad; Very bad". I would like to know if is possible to divide the values in the combobox. So it would be:

```
Very Good
Good
Normal
Bad
Very Bad
```

I saw in the internet that if the values were in different fields, is possible to do it. but to divide from one only one field it can be done?

```
If retVal Then

        Dim somestring As String = rs.Fields("Answer").Value
        Dim somestring2() As String
    somestring2 = somestring.Split(";")

        For i = 0 To somestring2.Length - 1
            While dr.Read
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(somestring2(i)))

            End While
            dr.Close()

        Next

    End If
```

I am having this trouble! Why?

> Conversion from string "Very bad" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Split the string and add the parts as items to the combobox.

Comment: @Gustav how can i split the string from the field?

Comment: Use the _Split_ method.

Comment: @Gustav thanks! I am on the right way I guess....but now I having another trouble, do you know what is that? I updated my question...to show the code i got it...I think thats enough info to understand...Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (not sure what dr is):

```
If retVal Then

    Dim somestring As String = rs.Fields("Answer").Value
    Dim somestring2() As String

    somestring2 = somestring.Split(";")
    For i = 0 To somestring2.Length - 1
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(somestring2(i))
    Next

End If
```